# How to prevent a character field containing numbers from converting to numeric?

Tags: oracle

How to prevent a varchar field containing numbers from converting to numeric in oracle sql?  This occurs only if used in a join.

Example

a varchar column named tbl1.col1 contains '012345'

```
select tbl1.col1 from tbl1 

012345
-- result OK
```

used in a join:

```
select tbl1.col1 from tbl1 inner join tbl2 on tbl1.key = tbl2.key  

12345
-- result not OK, converted to numeric.
```

Comment: A join does not automagically change the data type of a column. You would probably need to build a minimum reproducible example that demonstrates the problem better.

Comment: Is `tbl2.key` a number?  If so, does it have the value 12345?  If so, what do you want to happen when you join the two tables?  For no row to be returned?  Or for `012345` to be returned?  If so, how does the database know that the number 12345 is equivalent to the string '012345'?

Comment: Where exactly did you notice that behaviour? Is it in your tool (such as SQL Developer), or is it when you "export" data to - for example - Excel worksheet?

Comment: Thanks GMB, Justin Cave, Littlefoot.:  tbl1.col1 is a varchar containing the text '012345', i get 12345 if I use tbl1 in a join. .I want to to remain '012345',  i read on the oracle support site that oracle does an implicit conversion for such cases of purely numeric figures.  The SQL is executed in  oracle sqldeveloper reports, output eventually landing in excel.  We also tried a to_char() function even if the column is a varchar field, same results.